# I can see cookie content only in the page has setted it. Why?

Tags: php, cookies

I don't know if it has been asked before, but I don't know what to search for this issue.
I have a page with a form and an AJAX request. The PHP code check in asynchronous if the user exists and it set a cookie when the user ask for an automatic access. The cookie is setted, the code seems to work well. If I try to read the cookie content in the same page with the login form (after a refresh, this is normal - I know), I can see it. But when I try to read the same cookie content from another page, the cookie doesn't exist. It's like if it's not setted. How is this possible?

To make a test I also deactivated the JS redirect once the jquery script receive a success response, but it doesn't fix the issue.

PHP that runs with the jquery.ajax request (it shows me the right text):

```
setcookie("access", $string, time()+31536000);
if(isset($_COOKIE['access'])) echo "Cookie exists.<br>";
echo "Cookie content: ".$_COOKIE['access'];
```

connection.php called in other web site pages (the cookie seems to be empty or inexistent):

```
require_once("connection.php");

if(isset($_COOKIE["access"]))
{
  echo "I'm in!<br>";
  echo "Cookie content: ".$_COOKIE['access'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setcookie` function accepts a 4th parameter, named `$path`, that restricts where the cookie is accessible. By default $path is the page that set the cookie. If, instead, you want to the cookie to be accessible from all pages, you need to set the $path parameter to the root of your domain, so `/`.

Here's a quick fix for your code

```
setcookie("access", $string, time()+31536000, "/");
```

More info about the setcookie parameters can be found in the official [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: Quick and painless! Thank you :)